# Datatables child row without ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Can anyone guide me on how to use the child rows without ajax method mentioned here?
I don't need the ajax as I have data already with me.. so I am printing the HTML directly but not sure how to do it for child similarly as shown here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

this is how they do with ajax
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

this is what i tried adding to the basic table html

```
<tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Full name:</td>
                                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
            </tr>
```

But i didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question. Are you trying to add child rows to that HTML table that you post or are you trying to nest that table into a child row? Can you post your JQuery for the datatable?

Also, what format is your data?